# FastAPI SQLAlchemy delete Many-to-Many relation causes StaleDataError

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, many-to-many, fastapi

I have an error upon deleting a ManyToMany relation from table. I found that the problem caused by same items in `bills_dishes` table, but I need to add same items.

So, the code below works fine for items without duplicates like:

```
bill_id | dish_id
1       | 1
1       | 2
```

Models:

```
bills_dishes_association = Table(
    "bills_dishes",
    Base.metadata,
    Column("bill_id", Integer, ForeignKey("bills.id")),
    Column("dish_id", Integer, ForeignKey("dishes.id")),
)


class Waiter(Base):
    """Waiter model."""

    __tablename__ = "waiters"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    username = Column(String(50), nullable=False)
    password = Column(String(6), nullable=False)
    bills = relationship("Bill")

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Waiter(id={self.id}, username={self.username})"


class Bill(Base):
    """Bill model."""

    __tablename__ = "bills"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    waiter_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("waiters.id"), nullable=False)
    table_number = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    amount = Column(Float, nullable=False)
    tip_percent = Column(Integer)
    tip_included = Column(Boolean, default=False, nullable=False)
    time = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), server_default=func.now())

    dishes = relationship(
        "Dish", secondary=bills_dishes_association, back_populates="ordered"
    )

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Bill(id={self.id}, table_number={self.table_number}, amount={self.amount})"


class Dish(Base):
    """Dish model."""

    __tablename__ = "dishes"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String(100), nullable=False)
    description = Column(String(1024), nullable=False)
    image_url = Column(String(500), nullable=False)
    cost = Column(Float)

    ordered = relationship(
        "Bill",
        secondary=bills_dishes_association,
        back_populates="dishes",
        cascade="all, delete",
        passive_deletes=True,
    )
```

crud.py:

```
def delete_bill(db: Session, bill_id: int):
    """Delete a bill by id."""
    db_bill = db.query(Bill).filter(Bill.id == bill_id).first()
    db.delete(db_bill)
    db.commit()
    return db_bill
```

But it doesn't work for this case:

```
bill_id | dish_id
1       | 2
1       | 2

sqlalchemy.orm.exc.StaleDataError: DELETE statement on table 'bills_dishes' expected to delete 1 row(s); Only 2 were matched.
```

How to handle this?

Comment: "but I need to add same items" - Please [edit] your question to explain why you think that you need duplicate rows in your association table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to set `passive_deletes=True` on the `dishes` relationship in `Bill` and also add `ondelete="CASCADE"` to both foreign keys in the `bills_dishes_association`.

Although for a critical table you might be better off elevating `bills_dishes` to something more like `bill_lines` and promoting it to a full blown Model like `BillLine` such that `Bill` -- 1tomany -- `BillLine` -- manyto1 -- `Dish` and giving it its own PK id:

[sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.passive_deletes](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.passive_deletes)